# making ios 6 app project compatible with iOS 5 - backwards

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

This question is for iOS 5 with Xcode 4.2. That's what I am running for iOS development.

I have download a sample project from git hub [InstaOverlay](https://github.com/mmackh/MAImagePickerController-of-InstaPDF) and when I look at its target it says "6.0" so I switched it to 5.0 and tried compiling the code. I wasn't able to go very far as you can see from my screenshot. Tons and Tons of errors.

So my question is, is there a problem with the code itself or projects that are made for iOS 6 can never be made to run on iOS 5? I thought users are able to make apps backward compatible?

Any suggestions

[image]

Comment: Hi Sam, I'm Max - the developer of Instaoverlay. The issues you're encountering might be related to the XCode version rather than the iOS SDK. InstaPDF, the app that I wrote the component for is actually targeted for 5.1

Comment: Also - Are you sure you have correctly added all the dependencies?

Comment: Hi Mmackh - are you sure its just iOS 5.1 problem. I think it may not be that simple - I get most errors for CV_XADD - which is for opencv2 - unfortunately there is no way for me to verify if it really does work on iOS 5.1 or not since I am running iOS 5 with Xcode 4.2

Comment: @Adbizem - All I did was download and open instaoverlay project and try compiling it. I didn't create my own project to incorporate it - all dependencies should have been included in instaoverlay proj.

Comment: No, I'm sure that it isn't an iOS problem, because I think it is your Xcode version.

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific - I did a straight git clone of the project, changed the deployment target to 5.0 and it built and ran without errors. So - to answer the question - the project isn't broken - it's something local to your machine.

Comment: @Abizern - how more specific can I be? Do you not see my screenshot? Did you try with Xcode 4.2 or are you running the latest Xcode? To be more specific if needed this is the error I keep getting - CV_XADD expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction. Its compiling about this specific function error 22 times at various places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General answer**

Yes, apps can be made backwards compatible with iOS5 or earlier. "Can be" being the important catch here -- **doing so can be very time consuming**, depending on what your application does, what APIs it uses, etc. On the other handle, quite simple projects can just work, if they use very standard APIs available without much change since the beginning of (iOS) time.

Obviously if your app uses iOS6 only features, you're stuck. Otherwise, yes, you can do it, but be prepared to take time doing so -- not only writing/alterting code, but testing it.

So as far as you're concerned, yes, the project is 'broken', by which we mean not written for older versions of iOS. If only it were as simple as changing a project setting!

Here's a few strategies for making backwards-compatible apps:

- **Where variants on an API exist, with different methods having different compatability, use the most compatible variants.** For example, some `NSFileManager` methods appeared in newer versions of iOS, but older variations will still work. Apple tend to willy-nilly publish source code (IME) that uses the newer code without any proviso about "BTW, this won't work on older versions of iOS" so care is needed
- **If you want to make some functionality only appear on newer iOS versions, you need to do a run-time check that the desired methods/APIs are available, and only use them when they are.** In these cases you also need to be careful linking your project and 'weak link' some items.
- If you really need iOS3 compatability, you can't use ARC; it has to be old-style memory management. iOS4 supports ARC, but a few runtime limitations: auto-nilling of references isn't supported.

Movie playing is a classic example of newer and better APIs being available but older APIs still being around. The older `MPMoviePlayerController` was pre-iOS4, then `MPMoviePlayerViewController` appeared in iOS4 (note the word 'view' -- it's a fully fledged `UIViewController`). Typically you want to use the latter, but for iOS3 compatability you'd decide to use the former based on a runtime check.

**Specific answer**

Your problem with `CV_XADD`: this looks like a preprocessor definition that is `#define`d somewhere but the compiler isn't picking it up. For a hint, try looking for the definition of `CV_XADD` by searching for `#define CV_XADD`. IF you can't find that, try looking for just `CV_XADD` and looking for a definition in all the results.

Have you tried googling for the terms 'CV_XADD expected expression'? I get a number of hits relating to this problem.

Your project is using C++ which adds some more complexity to the mix!

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation occulus - I wanted to get a confirmation from someone more experienced than me that the project is broken. Keeps complaining about CV_XADD - which has nothing to do with Apple Apis.

Comment: Hi Sam, I've added a bit to the end of my answer about your specific problem.

Comment: lol - seriously man i give up. All I was trying to do is see what these guys had put together on github and how it works. If I can't even compile it with C++ compiler layer complexity added then its just a waste of my time. Thank you for all your explanations!